# Slack Stackstorm issue with mysql pack

Tags: slack, python-unicode

I am facing am issue with Slack - Stackstorm integration. For the [mysql pack](https://github.com/StackStorm-Exchange/stackstorm-mysql) I have to pass a string(which is a mysql query) as argument in the command. There is an equal to(=)  symbol in the string, which is considered as a different parameter by Stackstorm. Just want to know if this is a right behavior from Stackstrom. If So how can I execute the command by passing queries with conditions like this?

Please find the command that I tried from Slack

```
mysql select community SELECT * FROM county_target where county_name='Franklin'
```

Log

> 2017-10-19 07:06:31,205 139817071963664 DEBUG action_param_utils [-]
>   Casting param: SELECT * FROM county_target where of type  to type: string 2017-10-19 07:06:31,205 139817071963664
>   DEBUG action_param_utils [-] Casting param: community of type  to type: string 2017-10-19 07:06:31,205 139817071963664
>   DEBUG action_param_utils [-] Will skip cast of param[name:
>   county_name, value: Franklin]. No schema. 2017-10-19 07:06:31,220
>   139817071963664 ERROR aliasexecution [-] Unable to execute action.
>   Parameter validation failed.